# ASP website stops working when IIS6 is set to .NET 4

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp-classic

I am having 2 web site one is written with ASP the other one with ASP.NET (4).
In my web server (IIS) when do set for dot net to version 4, the web which is written in .NET works fine but stops working the one with ASP. I did changed in several way but I am having to make both sites in the same time. If anyone has any answer will be appreciated.

- Windows is 2003 server,
- IIS is version 6
- ASP.NET is from 2 to 4

Comment: You really ought to do some upgrading.

Comment: first website is written in which asp.net version ?

Comment: Probably a better fit at ServerFault.com - it's an IIS issue, not a coding issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Create two virtual directories in your IIS. One for the Asp.Net 4 and one for the other version of Asp.net. Select Virtual directory and select properties and then Set the desire asp.net version.